# How to pass two parameter in Cakephp ajax observedfield

Tags: ajax, cakephp-2.0

How to pass two parameter in `Cakephp` `ajax` `observedfield`

I have to pass a custom parameter in `$this->Ajax->observeField()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using 1.3 Version or lower since this is not available in 2.x. From the Cookbook http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/AJAX.html, the AJAX Helper method for observeField accepts 2 parameters

```
observeField(string $fieldId, array $options)
```

Try passing in $options array the required parameter as

```
'paramName' => 'paramValue'
```

You should be able to access this inside controller using

```
$this->params
```

Comment: in $options i need to pass one id (custom id)

Comment: I m using  2.x version

Comment: can u please give me some idea about "with" parameter in $option